# Regex problems while submitting

Tags: php, regex

I have problem on my website while submitting news. Everything works well, and news is submitted but I'm receiving this error message.

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '/' in C:\xampp\htdocs\submit_articles.php on line 121
```

Here's the  code which I've edited (I just added [^\w\d]/si',) but regex is unknown to me.

```
$NewImageName = preg_replace(array('[^\w\d]/si','\s/', '/\.[\.]+/', '/[^\w_\.\-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), strtolower($PostTitle));
```

Comment: you forget to add a delimiter at the first and at the second ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with:

```
$NewImageName = preg_replace(array('/[^\w\d]/si','/\s/', '/\.[\.]+/', '/[^\w_\.\-]/'), array('_', '.', ''), strtolower($PostTitle));
```

regexes in preg need to be enclosed in / ... /, and modifiers put after the later /.

Comment: <img src="timthumb.php?src=http://localhost/uploads/sadr��aj_879569608.jpg&amp;h=50&amp;w=50&amp;q=100" alt="sadržaj" class="img-responsive"> �� Getting those in image src, because of that image is not showing. It's because regex code. Code is working, but that path after is not showing correctly. Containing letters "šđčćž"

Comment: you need to post more details about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @EldarRibić You're probably looking to match unicode characters with PHP regex. Google will tell you how.

Comment: Regex need to "read" or whatever it's called šđčćž letters. If I try with regex u fixed, it's ok, but the path is wrong. "localhost/uploads/sadr��aj_879569608.jpg". �� should be šđčćž